# Setting Dynamic Border Width in CSS

Tags: css, dynamic, width, border

How can I set [this](http://pinarongun.com) image's border dynamically. (The picture is always changing so don't offer me a fixed px size) Height is ok with 100% but when I tried the same solution to the "width" it wasn't working. I try everything like; !important, 100%, auto, etc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you apply the border to the image itself?

Comment: Not a real question – does not specify what the problem in setting width is and how height and width relate to the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Just specify a standard CSS border on the image - it will automatically adjust to the height and width of the image.  Example:

```
img {
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

Or check out http://jsfiddle.net/F45T8/.